# Windows XP Sound Controls take a long time to open

Tags: windows-xp, audio, delay

I'm using WinXP SP3, and when I double-click on the sound icon in the system tray, it can take up to 20 seconds for the sound control window to open.

No other system tray icons take as long to load.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I surely don't know *why* this is happening... but I know that it's pretty much a cosmisc constant in the Windows XP universe. Volume control in Windows XP has never failed to take its sweet time to open on any computer that I've ever seen it on. It varies a bit with general system performance and such, but in general, it always takes *at least* 5 seconds.